# SQL - Combine rows

Tags: sql-server

I have rows in a table that looks like this:

```
[date],[name],[duty],[holiday],[hdaypart],[sick],[sdaypart]

2015-04-27, person1, 1,0,NULL,0,NULL

2015-04-27, person1, 0 1,'fd',0,NULL
```

I would like to combine these rows to:

```
[date],[name],[duty],[holiday],[hdaypart],[sick],[sdaypart]

2015-04-27, person1, 1,1,'fd',0,NULL
```

The duty, holiday and sick columns as BIT columns.

Is there way to do this?

The one solution I can come up with is using subqueries, but it consumes a lot of time. A faster solution would be nice.

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [name],[date],[region],[cluster]
,CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT,callduty)) FROM planning AS t2
            WHERE t1.[Date] = @datum AND t2.[Name] = t1.[name] AND t2.[Date] = t1.[date] ) > 0
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CallDuty]
,CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT,holiday)) FROM planning AS t2
            WHERE t1.[Date] = @datum AND t2.[Name] = t1.[name] AND t2.[Date] = t1.[date] ) > 0
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Holiday]

FROM planning AS t1
where t1.[Date] = @datum AND t1.[Name] like @naam
group by t1.[date],t1.[name], t1.Region, t1.cluster
order by t1.[name]
```

Comment: You haven't told us what criteria/algorithm you want to use to combine the rows!

Comment: Share your current solution so we can see the baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your example, I assume that you want to get the maximum values for a specific user.

You could do this using a group by and max

```
select max([date]),[name],max([duty]),max([holiday]),max([hdaypart]),max([sick]),max([sdaypart])
from yourtable
group by name
```

This is not really pretty but should perform better than using subqueries.

EDIT:
If you have columns with bit sql types, use

```
max(cast([bitColumn] as int))
```

Adding the date column in the group by, as suggested by Giorgos Betsos, the result is

```
select [date],
       [name],
       max([duty]),
       max([holiday]),
       max(cast([hdaypart] as int)),
       max(cast([sick] as int)),
       max(cast([sdaypart] as int))
from yourtable
group by [date],[name]
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to group by date and name and select either the maximum or the not null values within each group. `MAX` aggregate function is suitable for both of these selections:

```
SELECT [date],[name], MAX([duty]), MAX([holiday]),
       MAX([hdaypart]), MAX([sick]), MAX([sdaypart])
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [date],[name]
```

Comment: The duty, holiday and sick columns are BIT columns. MAX() doesn't work on those.

Comment: @Eric You should have included this info in the OP

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table ([date] date,[name] varchar(10),[duty] varchar(10),[holiday] int,[hdaypart] varchar(10),[sick] int,[sdaypart]
int
)
insert into @t([date],[name],[duty],[holiday],[hdaypart],[sick],[sdaypart])values ('2015-04-27','person1',1,0,NULL,0,NULL),
('2015-04-27','person1',1,0,'fd',0,NULL)

select MAX([date]),MAX([name]),MAX([duty]),MAX([holiday]),MAX([hdaypart]), [sick],[sdaypart] from @t
group by sick,[sdaypart]
```

OR

```
select [date],[name],[duty],[holiday],MAX([hdaypart])AS H,[sick],[sdaypart] from @t
group by [date],[name],[duty],[holiday],[sick],[sdaypart]
UNION 
select [date],[name],[duty],[holiday],MAX([hdaypart])AS H,[sick],[sdaypart] from @t
group by [date],[name],[duty],[holiday],[sick],[sdaypart]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Combine
(
    [date] date,
    [name] VARCHAR(10),
    [duty] CHAR(1),
    [holiday] CHAR(1),
    [hdaypart] CHAR(5),
    [sick]  CHAR(1),
    [sdaypart] VARCHAR(10)

)

INSERT INTO #Combine VALUES('2015-04-27', 'person1', '1','0',NULL,'0',NULL),

('2015-04-27', 'person1', '0','1','fd','0',NULL)


SELECT MAX(Date) [date],MAX(name) [name],MAX(Duty) [duty],MAX(holiday) holiday,
MAX(hdaypart) hdaypart,max(sick) sick,max(sdaypart)sdaypart FROM #Combine
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue